# My BGE Message actuator does not work although others are working

Tags: game-engine

I'm having a really big problem with my message actuator. I need you to help me find the root of the problem.

This is the image of the object's logic that sends the message below:
[image]

And this is the image of the object's logic that receives the message:

[image]

Although others are working (which shown green), message shown in red doesn't work and i don't know why?
I tried most of things but it didn't help.

*I'm sending messages between scenes.

*I tried to change the name of the object and didn't work.

*In my previous save files, it was working and this file goes the same way.

*I checked other discussions but nothing would help

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Problem occurs from mouse clicks. When i set for keyboard press it works but mouse click (mouse over + left button) does not work. Does anyone know why not?